# Mosquitto error: only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am seeing this error with Mosquitto, can someone please tell me how to solve the problem?

```
λ mosquitto -v
1483089866: mosquitto version 1.4.9 (build date 08/06/2016 11:59:29.51) starting
1483089866: Using default config.
1483089866: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1483089866: Error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message implies that you are trying to reuse port 1883.

Best guess with so little to work with is that you already have an instance of mosquitto (or some other broker) running on the machine that is already bound to port 1883

The error message is one from Windows, so it probably means that mosquitto is running as a service

Comment: THANKS.I solved the problem. Can you please tell me the command to read the message on console which is sent by my arduino through mosquitto broker

Comment: If this helped, mark the answer as accepted and ask a new question about subscribing to massages

Comment: I have seen this problem even when my Microsoft Windows 7's Task Manager has shown that the Mosquitto broker is not running.  When this has happened, I had started and stopped mosquitto.exe several times before the problem occurred.   I suspect that something was left behind the last time that I stopped mosquitto.exe that made it appears that the socket was still in use.  Rebooting worked around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

go to command prompt administrator

run the command
netstat -ano | findstr1883

then kill the process
taskkill /F /PID 4464

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74624733/edit) the answer to add more context. (e.g. this looks like a set of Windows commands, but the OP doesn't mention any OS, also where does 4464 come from in the second command?)